# Tailwind group-hover not working (even with default variants)

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind's `group-hover` is not working for me. I'm simply trying to change text color, which doesn't require any special config.

Am I forgetting something?

For reference my project is a Vue (Nuxt.js) app, all other Tailwind features are working for me and I've used TW group-hover on other projects without issue.

**FAILS:**
Tried the following on a basic welcome page in my app.

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="group-hover:text-gray-300">Hover me</div>
    <div class="group-hover:text-red-300">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

**WORKS:** The same code works fine in Codepen https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/MWjroVZ

**My `tailwind.config.js`:**

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms')
  ],
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      'components/**/*.vue',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.js',
      'nuxt.config.js'
    ]
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        brandGreen: {
          light: '#5bb751',
          default: '#5bb751',
          dark: '#3b7935',
          darker: '#33602e'
        }

      }
    },
    screens: {
        'xs': '480px'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a fix, but I don't understand it.

I had to explicitly define the `group-hover` variant for text color, even though text color is a basic property that should work by default without having to do this, [as per the TW docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover).

For other basic TW projects I never had to do this. [My Codepen example](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/MWjroVZ) works without any special config. Maybe the config is required for my context of Nuxt+TW? I also tested the original issue with PurgeCSS disabled and that had no effect.

**Solution:**

In `tailwind.config.js`, explicitly define a `group-hover` variant for `textColor`, even though it's supposed work without this (for basic properties like text color):

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

  variants: {
    textColor: ['group-hover'],
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried that but it didn't work. It use to work perfectly, then seldomly (would work on some element but not all) and now, it's not working at all...

Comment: Well, all I can advise is that while you trial-and-error, keep in mind when you are relying on A) hot reload vs B) re-starting the app vs C) re-building the app. Usually when I experience intermittent bugs in CSS, it's because I'm doing something different in this regard.